# How to search ASCII text with Ubuntu Terminal

Tags: command-line, files, ascii

I have a file in which when I use the `file myFile` I get returned `myFile: ASCII text, with very long lines`

I then proceeded to open it up as a .txt file and it opens up in notepad as a lot of ip addresses. For example `127.0.0.1 - - [20/Feb/2014:19:35:31 -0700] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 6008 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0"`
and so on for various lines.

Is there a way to search through this ASCII text to find unique IP addresses and which has the most "hits"? I am having trouble finding this type of command since I am not even sure I am suppose to open it in a .txt file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `grep` to extract the IP addresses, and `sort` + `uniq` to count the number of hits:

```
grep -Po '^\d+(\.\d+){3}' filename | sort | uniq -c
```

- `grep` is used to search for text matching a regular expression
- `-o` prints only the text that matched the expression, and not the entire line
- `-P` enables Perl-style regular expressions
- `^\d+(\.\d+){3}` - a string that matches:

  1. The beginning of the line (`^`) followed by
  2. Any number of digits (`\d+`) followed by
  3. A dot and any number of digits (`\.\d+`) repeated 3 times (`{3}`)
- `sort` sorts the input
- `uniq -c` prints the number of unique entries in sorted input.

Comment: This is amazing! It prints out beautifully. May I ask though what the first number in front of each IP address is? Is that the number of times that IP address was repeated?

Comment: @Robert yes, so that would be the number of hits you needed.

Comment: Ah okay so that's perfect, just print out the output to a file and sort through all those that only have 1 and it will give me only the unique ones then! Thank you so much!

Comment: @Robert you can tack on `| awk '$1 == 1'` at the end for that.

Comment: I cant thank you enough, learning ubunto and shell has been so much fun and even better with such a great community.